# Python not releasing serial port

Tags: python, pyserial

I open the serial port, read some parameters from the modem (Omited here for simplicity), close the serial port and call sakis3g, a script to connect to Internet through a serial or USB modem.

I can connect calling sakis3g from console.

The code:

```
# -*- coding: ISO-8859-1 -*-
import serial
import time
from subprocess import call

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600, timeout=0)
port.open()
at_ok=False 

#wait until modem answers with an OK
while at_ok==False:
    port.write(bytes("AT\n", 'ISO-8859-1'))
    time.sleep(.5)
    r=port.read(1000)
    if len(r)>0:
        if r.decode("ISO-8859-1").find("OK")>0:
            print ("Connected to modem")
            at_ok=True

port.close()

time.sleep(1) #just in case

call(["sakis3g","connect","--pppd"])
```

The output:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# python3 /usr/test2.py
Connected to modem
Port /dev/ttyAMA0 is currently occupied by 14057 python3.
Failed to connect.
```

(I'm using a raspberry)
Edit: I used port.isOpen() just before the call, and it returns False.

This is part of the output of sakis3g when I use the --debug option:

```
[20574] [16:57:04] We are root already. Proceeding.
[20574] [16:57:04] Device /dev/ttyAMA0 is currently occupied by 0 process(es).
[20574] [16:57:04] PID(s) are: 20542
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20574] [16:57:04] Will now run command: \'/bin/ps -p 20542 -o pid,comm= | /usr/bin/tail -1\'
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20542 python3
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20574] [16:57:04] Command returned 0.
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20574] [16:57:04] Will wait for 10 seconds in case port is freed.
[20574] [16:57:05] Verbosing: 21% Waiting /dev/ttyAMA0 to be released by PID 20542 python3.
[20574] [16:57:05] Wait for another 10 seconds in case port /dev/ttyAMA0 is freed.
```

Edit2:
I think I've found the problem (not the solution):
I made a python script that do the folowing:
- Wait 10 seconds
- Open serial port
- Wait another 10 seconds
- Close serial port
- Wait forever

Using `lsof|grep ttyA` I get:

before opening the port:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# lsof|grep ttyA
root@raspberrypi:~#
```

When the port is open:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# lsof|grep ttyA
python3     530            root    3u      CHR     204,64      0t0          9 /dev/ttyAMA0
python3     530            root    4u      CHR     204,64      0t0          9 /dev/ttyAMA0
root@raspberrypi:~#
```

After the port closes:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# lsof|grep ttyA
python3     530            root    3u      CHR     204,64      0t0          9 /dev/ttyAMA0
root@raspberrypi:~#
```

So pyserial or python is keeping the port occupied, but not locked?

Comment: I start to suspect `port.read(1000)` is still consuming the python process as it never completes. It's a wild guess again but could you try doing a `flushInput()` after or using `readline()` instead and see if this helps?

Comment: Another wild guess: Did you terminate the python interpreter? You can open the same port multiple times in a single session, which can happen if you script terminates with an error before closing. You also could do as root ``apt-get install lsof`` and then ``lsof |grep /dev/ttyA`` to see which program has the port open.

Comment: I changed the read() for readline() and added flushInput(), same behavior.
 Using lsof |grep /dev/ttyA returned: python3   18783            root    3u      CHR     204,64      0t0          9 /dev/ttyAMA0
So python is keeping the port open, but if I try to read from the port after the port.close(), the programs quits because the port is closed